# angular .$save is not a function

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-resource

My project is base on ionic framework, and I am using ngResource in project. Now my requirement is that I want to pass the url dynamically to that ngResource function. For this I create one wrapper for this. And its working properly with get, put, getone method but I have an issue while submitting data to the server and I got this error **.$save is not a function**. [Check this code for more detail.](https://github.com/rahulsalvikar777/movieapp.git)

Wrapper

```
angular.module('ClientAPI.services', [])
.factory('ClientAPI', function ($resource) {
    var _passUrl;
    var _passParameters;

    return{
        passUrl:_passUrl,
        passParameters: _passParameters,
        callAPIClient : function(){
            return  $resource( this.passUrl, this.passParameters, {
                'update': {
                    method: 'PUT'
                }
            })
        },
        setURL: function(url){
            this.passUrl = url
        },
        setParameters: function(params){
            this.passParameters = params;
        }
    }

})
```

Use in Code :

```
$scope.movie = new ClientAPI.callAPIClient();
    $scope.addMovie = function () {
        $scope.movie.$save(function () {
            $state.go('app.movies');
        });
    }
```

for more detail please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24246870/i-am-getting-a-save-not-a-function-in-angular)

Comment: most people will not download a .git repository in order to troubleshoot an issue of this nature.  Also, you didn't include the line of code that is causing this error in your question.

Comment: Paste a code of when the error occurs - that is how you are using the service and which method are you calling and how you are calling it. No - providing the Github URL does not work.

Comment: I already try this thing but its not working. like this-> save: {method: 'POST'}. That's why I post git hub repository URL.

Comment: I update the question please refer this...

Comment: 1. why do you define a method for `$resource` which already exists with [same options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) (see section Returns)? 2. after defining `save` method why would call it like `.$save()`? the method name is `.save()`...